# how to output the property of the selected element in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="aGoogle1">Google Link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{

        console.log($('a[href="http://www.google.com"]'));
});
</script>
```

In chrome->console, I can see `$('a[href="http://www.google.com"]')` returns the selected element, and I can see it has this property: id: "aGoogle1". so my question is:

How to output the property, e.g. id, I tried `$('a[href="http://www.google.com"]'.id)`, but it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to get the attributes of an element. However there are some differences between two. check [attr() Vs prop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr). You can access the id by

```
$('a[href="http://www.google.com"]').attr('id');
```

or

```
$('a[href="http://www.google.com"]').prop('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) to get or set attributes

```
alert($('a[href="http://www.google.com"]').attr('id'));
```

this will get the id of selected elements

Answer (score 0):

Ue `attr`

```
  $('a[href="http://www.google.com"]').attr('id');
```

or `prop`

```
$('a[href="http://www.google.com"]').prop('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href="http://www.google.com"]'.id)
```

This code attempts to access the property `id` on the string object `'a[href="http://www.google.com"]'`; the outcome is `undefined`. Afterwards you're wrapping that inside a jQuery object. The outcome of that is an empty jQuery set.

You need to always start from here:

```
$('a[href="http://www.google.com"]')
```

And then use jQuery functions to do what you need. In your case you wish to access the property of the anchor element, so you use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('a[href="http://www.google.com"]').prop('id')
```